# how to offset polylines in r using leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, gis

I am currently mapping several city connections (polylines) using leaflet in R/shiny which works perfectly fine. However, there are several lines on top of each other and I'd like to be able to offset these overlapping lines.

There is already a great plug-in by *bbecquet* for leaflet that does the job but it's not implemented in the R package (yet?).

https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset

My current solution is pretty much "hands-on" as I simply shift the lines depending on the zoom-level.

```
# temp2 is a SpatialLinesDataFrame
negs <- as.matrix(coordinates(temp2[1,])[[1]][[1]])
negs[,1] <- (negs[,1])+exp(input$map_zoom)
negs[,2] <- (negs[,2])+exp(input$map_zoom) 
temp2@lines[[1]]@Lines[[1]]@coords[] <- negs
```

See example how it currently looks like.

[image]

Does any one have a better idea or knows how I could use the PolylineOffset plug-in in R? Cheers!

Comment: This shows a way to directly use a JS plugin with R leaflet https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/8f6c8cc27597466351ad377e6774c30f

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunatelly, I'm (and also others) are still struggling: https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92

Answer (score 2):

In the `ui` part of shiny add this:

```
tags$head(
    tags$script(src="leaflet.polylineoffset.js")
)
```

And place the javascript file in the `www` folder of your shiny app.
Then in the `server` part use the offset like this:

```
leafletProxy("my_map") %>%
addPolylines(data=coords, weight=1, options=list(offset=3))
```

In the example, there is already a map initialised called "my_map" and `coords` contains the coordinates of the polylines. The `offset` is in pixels indpendent of zoom level.

bbecquet did great work on this plugin, but unfortunately it didn't work properly for me. I adjusted the javascript code somewhat to resolve the issues. You can find my version here:
[modified offset javascript](https://trafficdash.nl/assets/leaflet.polylineoffset_arw.js)

It works only with the R `leaflet` package version 2 and higher which is based on a more recent version of leaflet.

Comment: The link you provided appears to be broken.

Comment: It is fixed now.